# Bluetooth Speaker Sony SRS-X5

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, adapter

Can I charge my bluetooth speaker with 12v adapter, if it says on him 12.5v?
Will it damage it or will it just charge slower?

Answer (score 1):

I see no issue.

Your 12V adapter will not output exactly 12V anyway. Half a volt in this case is no big deal.
Just make sure that:

1. the polarity of the adapter is the same as the device
2. the adapter is able to deliver (roughly) the current required by the device (the original adapter is rated 2.5A)